# How do I turn off headbob?

Tags: far-cry-4

Title says it all. Googled for about 15 minutes but got nothing. Inquiries in Ubisoft official forums and reddit are met with silence from everybody.

Checked GamerProfile.xml for "head", "bob" and "sway" keywords, nothing.

Comment: What is headbob?

Comment: How am I supposed to activate it? It's on by default. If I can manually activate it in the first place, I would've deactivated it myself. "Headbob" is a very prominent feature in recent FPS games I never thought someone could not know about it, it's where the camera bounces around to simulate your head bobbing when you move, thus instigating nausea on some people.

Comment: As far as I know you can't disable headbob. But from what I've read, increasing the FOV should counter the effects a bit, since it becomes less noticeable. Of course, increasing the FOV isn't always desirable, either, unfortunately.